# Why is the "write the app_id in a key as gadapplicationidentifier" prompt coming up?

Tags: xcode, testing, admob, ads

I'm trying to figure out why this prompt is coming up when it clearly exists in the apps info.plist?

> write the app_id in a key as gadapplicationidentifier

I've followed all steps offered by Google and the Admob account is not new. Is this common for apps in testing?

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DC7Z.png
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/oT1hE.png